# Is it possible to combine three strings in java using operator?

Tags: java

can anyone help to concatenate three strings in java? For example, if there are three strings a=this b=is c=march then the result has to be concatenated as "this is march"

Comment: String.format("%s %s %s", a, b, c)

Comment: this is simple just write `a+" "+b+" "+c` and that is it

Answer (score 0):

You can use + operator for this.

```
string result= a + b + c;
```

or do something like this

```
String a = new StringBuilder(b).append(c).append(d).toString();
```

Comment: In both cases you would get `thisismarch`!

Comment: note that `a+b+c` is syntactic sugar for `new StringBuilder(a).append(b).append(c).toString()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String result = a + " " + b + " " + c;
```

Or a another way:

```
String result = String.format("%s %s %s", a, b, c);
```

The `%s`s represent an area that will be replaced by a string, which is supplied by the corresponding argument in the rest of the method.

Comment: The "faster" way is neither faster nor shorter.

Comment: My bad, I meant less annoying to type (for me). I fixed it.